# Dialogbox does not focus

Tags: c#

Wrote a login custom dialogbox

```
static LoginDialog loginDialog;

public static bool ShowLoginDialog()
        {
            result = false; // Success

            loginDialog = new LoginDialog();

            loginDialog.ShowDialog();
            loginDialog.BringToFront();
            loginDialog.TopMost = true;
            loginDialog.Activate();

            return result;
        }
```

I call it from another form whitout my interaction, it is fire up when timer ticked:

```
LoginDialog.ShowLoginDialog();
```

The problem is the login screen does not focus on top of the current open form.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: `ShowDialog()` will block the execution of method.

Comment: @AVD: `ShowDialog()` will do block the the execution of method, but that's AFTER displaying the LoginDialog in dialog mode. So it shouldn't cause the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your `LoginDialog` is just another Form. Try this -

In the `MainForm`:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = 3000; // your preferred time-interval
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoginDialog.ShowLoginDialog(timer1);
    }
```

In the `LoginDialog`:

```
    private static bool result;
    private static LoginDialog loginDialog;

    public static bool ShowLoginDialog(Timer timer)
    {
        timer.Stop();

        result = false; // Success

        loginDialog = new LoginDialog();
        loginDialog.ShowDialog();

        return result;
    }
```

NOTE: I have no idea what the `result` variable you are using for.

Comment: I am doing just that in my code. The Login Dialog will not focus on top of the MainForm.

Comment: When I am still at the application, it works, but if the the apps is running at the background and I am doing soemthing else, wehn I come back to the app, the login dialog is not focus on top of the main form.

Comment: @KelvinFixx: when you come back, try to select the MainForm. you can't. because between these two windows the LoginDialog is in Focus. to implement the exact scenarion you want, you need to go for an MDI app, where the MainForm will be the mdi parent and the LoginDialog will be the mdi child.

Answer (score 1):

use SetForegroundWindow  inside the form you want to receive focus

```
[DllImport("user32")] 
public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);
```

and when the dialog form is shown call the function with the form handle;

```
void OnShown(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   SetForegroundWindow(this.Handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `loginDialog.TopMost = true;` before `loginDialog.ShowDialog();`

Why you are using a **static** method? I think this the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Suppose you have Form1  as your parent Form
//Add Button on it and on its Click Event
```

Just simply do:

```
public bool ShowLoginDialog()
    {
        bool result = false; // Success

        var  loginDialog = new LoginDialog();
        loginDialog.ShowDialog();

        return result;
    }
```

ShowDialog() always be on the top on the parent form where you execute it.

Regards

Comment: Are you saying the `var` will make a difference? Because otherwise he's doing this already.

Comment: I don't want to fire and event with button click.

Comment: What i did is just an example.

Comment: It works, but you cannot return any result from that dialogbox form.

Answer (score 0):

loginDialog.BringToFront(); is not invoked as ShowDialog() blocks execution.
Pass a owner form to ShowDialog.

Answer (score 0):

You say you are calling the `ShowLoginDialog()` from another form.  Can you alter your signature to be `public static bool ShowLoginDialog(Form parentForm)` or `public static bool ShowLoginDialog(IWin32WindowOwner parentForm)`?  If so, then you can do:

```
public static bool ShowLoginDialog(IWin32WindowOwner parentForm)
{
    using(LoginDialog loginDialog = new LoginDialog()) //Really should use using statement
    {
        loginDialog.ShowDialog(parentForm); //Set the parent form for the dialog
    }
}
```